# Steady State Temperature Distribution for Concentric Spheres

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Two concentric spheres, one with radius 1 at temp $20\cos{\theta}$ the other at radius 2 and temp $20$. The problem I have is that I apply the boundary conditions and get $$a_1 + b_1 = 20$$ $$2a_0 + b_0 = 40$$ with my $u$ being $$u = \Sigma (a_lr^l + b_l r^{-l-1})P_l(\cos{\theta})$$ but doesn't this mean I can't solve for my temperature? I don't have enough equations, do I? What would by my final answer?

Comment: What does $\theta$ mean in this problem?

Comment: angle from the vertical z direction in spherical coordinates.